# Removing row when only a single specific relationship exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a table `person` with a `uid` and an `email`.  I also have a table `parent_child` where I store parental relationships.  It has `parent_uid` and `child_uid`, which are both required references to the `uid` of the `person` table.

When I delete a `person`, I want to delete all children as long as:

1. The *child* does not have an email set.  I'm just checking for an @ sign for this due to how I use this field in other places.
2. The child does not have any other parents.

Right now I'm trying to do this, from a `BEFORE DELETE ON person` trigger, but I'm feeling like it's not the most efficient way to handle this.

```sql
FOR child IN SELECT DISTINCT child_uid FROM parent_child WHERE parent_uid = OLD.uid
LOOP
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        -- Any parent that is not me.
        SELECT 1
        FROM parent_child
        WHERE child_uid = child AND parent_uid <> OLD.uid
    ) THEN
        DELETE FROM person WHERE uid = child AND email NOT LIKE '%@%'
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: what do yo mean by single specific relationship?

Comment: Typically a single `DELETE` will be more efficient then a loop

Comment: And how would you write the above as a single delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no better way to do this than a trigger.

You would index `person(uid)`, `parent(parent_uid)` and `parent_child(child_uid)` for efficiency (one of the latter indexes should be unnecessary, because you'll have a primary key constraint on `parent_uid` and `child_uid`).

Comment: So I should have been clearer.  I'm definitely doing this via a trigger.  But is the code I showed above the most efficient way of doing it?

Comment: I can see no problem with your code. I have added hints for proper indexing.